# Source content not fitting within iframe on mobile

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to add an html iframe on my website but I can't seem to get the source content to stay within the iframe on mobile/resize to fit within the iframe on mobile.

This is my webpage (works as desired on desktop, doesn't work as desired on mobile) - https://www.stlpremierrealestate.com/search

This is the html i have inserted onto my site -

```
<div><iframe src="https://www.marissearch.com" width="100%" height="800" scrolling="yes"></iframe></div>
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Check the properties of the parent elements. Maybe you'r frame within the div is wrapped by another elements. Can't say so much with one line of markup.

Comment: Add in a meta viewport element into the form page, e.g.: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> - also the .maris_disclaimer element has a width of 550px, change this to a max-width for it to scale for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a brief look at the website you've provided, and the issue is unrelated to the iframe.

You have this CSS rule in your codebase which is giving you the undesired result on mobile devices:

```
.dmDesktopBody .dmInner {
    min-width: 960px;
}
```